# How to fix Admob message "cannot get data" with Unity ads mediation?

Tags: admob, mobile-ad-mediation, unityads

I am trying to fill my admob ads hollows, with unity ads using mediation. I followed this tutorial:
[admob with unity ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/unity?hl=es-419#android_5)
but after following all steps my unity ads are showing no impressions

Admob suggests the following:

-Ad units have been assigned incorrectly (works fine:tested with a real device and using the shake the mobile feature)

-SDK integration issues(works fine:tested with a real device and using the shake the mobile feature)

-Issues with your external ad source's account permissions(checked twice and seems API and others IDs are correct)

Any help or suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you.

[admob mediation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5jvj.png)

Edit:

I am receiving request but no impresions in Unity Ads Reporting

[Unity Ads Reporting Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQEJ8.png)